# Joining a complex scan with many vertices and a cube together to create a solid object

Tags: boolean-modifier, smooth

how could I smoothly join the geometry of the facial scan and the cube together, without altering any of the existing geometry in the face, to make one solid object?

I'm doing this because I wanted to 3D print a custom facial interface for a VR headset. I brought in a facial scan and cut all of the unnecessary geometry out. I also have the .stl file for the facial interface which I've added in there. The plan is to make the facial scan into a solid object so that it works with the boolean modifier, at which point I can bring an object in and cut all intersections with the face and the gasket so that it will serve as a customized facial interface, if that makes sense.

[image: face scan, face gasket, cube]

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you use boolean modifier(join)?

Comment: "without altering any of the existing geometry in the face" - you will at least need to alter the edges of the scan and fix the holes. I don't think there is a very specific answer or any one-click solutions for this. You just use modelling tools in Blender to fill the gap between your scan geometry and the cube. Sculpting tools may be useful to smooth parts of the scan. models should be joined(ctrl+j), then fill(f), bridge edge loops(ctrl+e -> l), extrude(e), merge(m) and other tools should be used to form needed geometry.